# TRS to RCA audio out, what am I not understanding?

Tags: studio-monitors

I have a UMC202HD USB Audio Interface (2 x 1/4" TRS Out L/R) handling all my computer audio output. I have been using a set of Mackie Powered Studio Monitors (RCA Input), and a Klipsch Powered Sub (RCA Input).

I am failing to understand what the best possible solution is for hooking up the monitors and sub to the TRS Outputs. I currently have a TRS to RCA cable coming out of both TRS outputs on the 202HD, however I assumed these cables would simply split the left and right signal respectively to both RCA outputs allowing me to hookup the L monitor and L sub RCA to one side, (and the same for the right on the other), but that did not work, I only get sound out of the R channel when doing this. It seems as if only one of the RCA ports on the TRS to RCA cable has signal!?

I could split the "Right (red)" RCA output on each TRS to RCA Cable, and get the desired effect, but this seems less than optimal, just having the "Left (white)" cable unplugged on both cables all the time.

I feel like I'm missing a fundamental understanding of how this setup works best. Thought I would ask here before settling, or buying more unneeded couplers/connectors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally say "look at their documentation" but Behringer's docs are usually abysmal & give no clues for anything like this. [I checked the manual for this & yup, abysmal.]

TRS outs to your studio monitors would usually be wired tip hot, ring cold, sleeve ground.
This means that to wire unbalanced you need to run tip to hot, then link cold & ground together.

This requires two cables L & R. It's nothing like a headphone/stero cable.